# Titration curve of strong acid with strong base

Tags: acid-base, ph, titration

I have a question regarding the titration curve for $\ce{HCl}$ titrated with $\ce{NaOH}$. Why does it look like it does, with a steep slope near the equivalence point and a flat slope at the beginning and end?